# zebra.service of quaggga library not active

Tags: virtualbox-networking

When I run command sudo service bgpd restart. I received: "A dependence job for bgpd.service failed. see journalctl -xe for detail". When I run journalctl -xe I see that:" bgpd.service: bound to unit zebra.sevice but unit isn't active"